# Programming Phoenix Dependencies, error no matching function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :gen.call/4
    (stdlib) gen.erl:150: :gen.call(#PID<0.2976.0>, :"$gen_call", :mode, :manual)
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:601: GenServer.call/3
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:651: Enum.each/2
```

---

```
erl -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] 
              [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
```

---

```
elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8]
              [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.4
```

Mix file

```
defmodule Rumbl.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :rumbl,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.2",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases(),
     deps: deps()]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Rumbl, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :comeonin]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.6"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0.1"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6.0"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
     {:comeonin, "~> 2.0"}]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcut or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"]]
  end
end
```

`$ mix compile` seems to work, but `$ mix test` returns the above error.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

Also see something like this when running phoenix.server.

```
testuser at testuserretina in ~/Code/phoenix/Archive/rumbl on master mix phoenix.server

=INFO REPORT==== 14-Feb-2017::18:58:25 ===
application: logger
exited: stopped
type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application rumbl: Rumbl.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Rumbl.Endpoint
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
** (RuntimeError) please set root: Path.expand("..", __DIR__) in your endpoint inside config/config.exs in order to use code reloading or watchers
(phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/adapter.ex:83: Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter.root!/1
(phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/adapter.ex:63: anonymous fn/2 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter.watcher_children/3
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1184: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/adapter.ex:21: Phoenix.Endpoint.Adapter.start_link/2
(stdlib) supervisor.erl:365: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
(stdlib) supervisor.erl:348: :supervisor.start_children/3
(stdlib) supervisor.erl:314: :supervisor.init_children/2
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
testuser at testuserretina in ~/Code/phoenix/Archive/rumbl on master
```

I wonder what the right dependencies are for going through the Programming Phoenix book.

config.exs

Added config.exs. [Typing random words to get passed code filter]

```
# This file is responsible for configuring your application
# and its dependencies with the aid of the Mix.Config module.
#
# This configuration file is loaded before any dependency and
# is restricted to this project.
use Mix.Config

# General application configuration
config :rumbl,
  ecto_repos: [Rumbl.Repo]

# Configures the endpoint
config :rumbl, Rumbl.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  secret_key_base: "ML7Aim+6iTSsIzWRgN82yovHnFmKTApkGvqnGFcxxbPwp33pFGfuDJKDeCByxY9J",
  render_errors: [view: Rumbl.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(html json)],
  pubsub: [name: Rumbl.PubSub,
           adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]

# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]

# Import environment specific config. This must remain at the bottom
# of this file so it overrides the configuration defined above.
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```

Comment: What `MIX_ENV=test mix do deps.get, compile` returns?

Comment: `
testuser at testuserretina in ~/Code/phoenix/Archive/rumbl on master MIX_ENV=test mix do deps.get, compile
Running dependency resolution...
All dependencies up to date
testuser at testuserretina in ~/Code/phoenix/Archive/rumbl on master
`

Comment: Edit: Included it in original post.

Comment: It looks like there's an error with the endpoint config, could you post your config.exs please?

Comment: i think the error is self understood. (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching. you are getting a response in one form, however the tuple or the map, is not matching with what you get

Comment: Added the edit.